# 200mb JSON to CSV Conversion

Tags: json, csv, large-data, large-files, opendata

I have a 200mb .json file I would like to concert to .csv.
I have no coding experience and have absolutely no idea how to do this.
Can anyone help me figure out how to this? Since the file is so large none of the online tools seem to be working.

Thank you very much,

Y

Comment: Two suggestions: 1- download LTFV https://web.archive.org/web/20140908181354fw_/http://swiftgear.com/ltfviewer/features.html, 2- learn and use Python for your conversion

Answer (score 0):

The [Structured Text Tools](https://github.com/dbohdan/structured-text-tools) github repository has an extensive list of tools for tasks like this. In particular, the [JSON](https://github.com/dbohdan/structured-text-tools#json) section lists several tools that can convert from JSON to CSV. You may find one of these works for you. 200mb is not so large, it should be handleable by one of these.